# Statistics of 1D discrete random walks

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, probability, brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

I have already asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3023955/) in Math.SE.

Let $P(n)$ be a probability distribution on the integers. Suppose a random walker starts off at the origin and, at every positive integer time, takes a step of length $n$ with probability $P(n)$.

This walker will revisit the origin over and over. Let me call 'excursions' the steps they take between two consecutive visits to the origin. I am interested in the distribution of excursion 'duration' (time interval between consecutive visits to the origin) and excursion 'reach' (position farthest from the origin reached during excursion).

These are simple concepts, so I imagine they have been much discussed in the literature. Question is: where can I find good discussions of these topics?

Comment: There need to be restrictions on $P(n)$ for anything you say to be true. For example, a random walker with $P(n)=0$ for $n<0$ will never return to the origin. So what are the restrictions you're imposing on $P(n)$?

Comment: It must be so that the walker returns to the origin infinitely often. I think this is all. Any reasonable $P(n)$ will do.

Comment: The problem of finding a "reasonable" nontrivial $P(n)$ is difficult. The simple random walk where $P(1)=P(-1)=1/2$ returns to the origin infinitely often, but any simple asymmetric random walk, where $P(1)=p,P(-1)=1-p,p\neq 1/2$, does not.

Comment: @probably_someone I mean any $P(n)$ which is even and normalized with finite variance will probably do. My interest is not in the possibilities for $P(n)$ but what is known about duration statistics and reach statistics, for any $P(n)$ that people may have considered.

Comment: Then the thing you're actually looking for is the variance and recurrence of a symmetric random walk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, by the [Chung-Fuchs theorem](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789812833860_0012), any mean-zero one-dimensional random walk is recurrent. This tells you what the proper assumption on the step-distribution $P$ is.

If, in addition, the step-distribution has finite variance $\sigma^2$, then the law of its excursions converges, after diffusive scaling, to the law of Brownian excursions (see, e.g., [Annals of Probability 4(1), 1976, 115-121](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176996189)). From this (and the detailed results about Brownian excursions) you can extract the information you want on the "reach".

Concerning the "duration", i.e. the random variable $T=\inf\{n>0:S_n=0\}$, [Kesten first proved](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02789990.pdf) that, as $n\to\infty$,
$$
\mathbb{P}_0(T=n) = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}} n^{-3/2}\,(1+o(1)).
$$
This result also holds under the assumption that the variance $\sigma^2$ is finite. There are certainly extensions to the case of infinite variance, as well as sharper results, but I don't know the state-of-the-art out of my head. Probably you can find that by looking at recent papers citing those.